# Why do I get this error message: Could not find a declaration file for module 'swagger-jsdoc'

Tags: node.js, typescript, swagger, typeerror

This is my installation results:

```
success Saved 19 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ bcrypt@5.0.1
├─ config@3.3.7
├─ cors@2.8.5
├─ dayjs@1.11.0
├─ dotenv@16.0.0
├─ jsonwebtoken@8.5.1
├─ lodash@4.17.21
├─ mongoose@6.3.0
├─ nanoid@3.3.2
├─ pino-pretty@7.6.1
├─ pino@7.10.0
├─ prom-client@14.0.1
├─ response-time@2.3.2
├─ swagger-jsdoc@6.2.0
├─ swagger-ui-express@4.3.0
└─ zod@3.14.4
info All dependencies
├─ bcrypt@5.0.1
├─ config@3.3.7
├─ cors@2.8.5
├─ dayjs@1.11.0
├─ dotenv@16.0.0
├─ jsonwebtoken@8.5.1
├─ lodash@4.17.21
├─ mongodb-connection-string-url@2.5.2
├─ prom-client@14.0.1
├─ socks@2.6.2
├─ swagger-jsdoc@6.2.0
├─ swagger-ui-express@4.3.0
└─ zod@3.14.4

success Saved 13 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ @types/bcrypt@5.0.0
├─ @types/body-parser@1.19.2
├─ @types/config@0.0.41
├─ @types/cors@2.8.12
├─ @types/express@4.17.13
├─ @types/jsonwebtoken@8.5.8
├─ @types/lodash@4.14.181
├─ @types/nanoid@3.0.0
├─ @types/node@17.0.24
├─ @types/pino@7.0.5
├─ @types/response-time@2.3.5
├─ ts-node-dev@1.1.8
└─ typescript@4.6.3
info All dependencies
├─ @types/bcrypt@5.0.0
├─ @types/body-parser@1.19.2
├─ @types/config@0.0.41
├─ @types/cors@2.8.12
├─ @types/express@4.17.13
├─ @types/jsonwebtoken@8.5.8
├─ @types/lodash@4.14.181
├─ @types/nanoid@3.0.0
├─ @types/node@17.0.24
├─ @types/pino@7.0.5
├─ @types/response-time@2.3.5
├─ ts-node-dev@1.1.8
└─ typescript@4.6.3
```

But I still get these error messages:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'swagger-jsdoc'. 'C:/Users/A/Desktop/desktop/base_code/back_bc_node/node_modules/swagger-jsdoc/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/swagger-jsdoc` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'swagger-jsdoc';`

Could not find a declaration file for module 'swagger-ui-express'. 'C:/Users/A/Desktop/desktop/base_code/back_bc_node/node_modules/swagger-ui-express/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/swagger-ui-express` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'swagger-ui-express';`
```

And This is how I try to import it:

```
import swaggerJsdoc from "swagger-jsdoc";
import swaggerUi from "swagger-ui-express";
```

I don't know why do I get this error message because it was working on my previous application but doesn't work in the new application.I tried to reinstall swagger but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I tried following suggested commands within the error message and it worked:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/swagger-jsdoc
npm i --save-dev @types/swagger-ui-express
```

But it also created a new file named `package-lock.json` inside my project that I don't know if is it a good thing or not, because I was using `yarn` and this was the first `npm` command I tried. Also I don't know if this new added file `package-lock.json` was necessary to my project or not?

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
yarn add @types/swagger-jsdoc swagger-jsdoc @types/swagger-ui-express swagger-ui-express
```

Then in your app.ts file

```
import swaggerJSDocs  from "swagger-jsdoc";
import swaggerUi  from "swagger-ui-express"
```